# Foreach-loop crashes when an object of another class is made

Tags: c#

I'm making a game for a school project and I've run into a problem. The teacher requires that I use polymorphism in the code so basically, I have two classes, X and Y and they inherit from the abstract base class K.

I have a list for K objects so that objects of X and Y can be put in the list.
So the problem is that I want to run through the list with a `foreach` loop but only check the X objects.

```
foreach ( X object in list)...
```

The game crashes as soon as an X object is created and I don't understand why!

```
foreach (GoldCoin gc in powerUps.ToList())
{
    if (gc.IsAlive)
    {
        player.speedY = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        powerUps.Remove(gc);
    }
```

The error message said

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Couldn't convert an object of the class X to the class Y.'

Comment: [Post code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the crash.

Comment: You want the members of the list that are 'X's? `foreach (X object in list.Where(l => l is X).Cast<X>()) { ... `

Comment: _Couldn't convert an object of the class X to the class Y._ - is that a typo? It doesn't fit with the rest of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your pseudocode, it seems that you are forcing every object in the list to be an object of type X. But if the list contains also objects of type Y then you cannot assign that object to an instance of X

Suppose your class are:

```
class K
{
    public int value {get;set;}

}

class X : K
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Y : K
{ 
    public decimal money { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    List<K> elements = new List<K>();
    elements.Add(new X { Name = "Steve" });
    elements.Add(new Y {money = 100});

    // This cannot work, the second element is a Y and doesn't have a Name property
    // foreach(X obj in elements)
    //     Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);

    // This works because only elements of type X are retrieved by the enumeration
    foreach(X obj in elements.OfType<X>())
       Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a ton dude! Quite an easy fix. Would it be easier to have two seperate lists for X and Y or is this the way to go? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: It depends on how you use that list. For example, if you need to pass around these list between methods you get a simpler life with a single list. If you often need to differentiate your elements then _perhaps_ two lists are more performant.